# zfs: filesystem has dependent clones

Tags: docker, ubuntu, zfs

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and using zfs on my system drive.

I am trying to remove a docker container but I get this error:

```sh
glen $ docker rm c3250e315b06
Error response from daemon: container c3250e315b0631cc7fee17ab0c7f649a3995ea17e969705117e064a045b3775e: driver "zfs" failed to remove root filesystem: exit status 1: "/usr/sbin/zfs fs destroy -r rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bl0u7i/var/lib/120f50d109cf1c84f20db9e6402fef9a4bd91fa8b94f1848a874539663bbdc40" => cannot destroy 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bl0u7i/var/lib/120f50d109cf1c84f20db9e6402fef9a4bd91fa8b94f1848a874539663bbdc40': filesystem has dependent clones
use '-R' to destroy the following datasets:
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bl0u7i/var/lib/38ff67538bf4b2ccfef54cfeb55847cf6da6bee70a6bf2e5b063ab0e5820c0fd
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bl0u7i/var/lib/120f50d109cf1c84f20db9e6402fef9a4bd91fa8b94f1848a874539663bbdc40-init
```

I have no idea where to start with the error.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

I fixed it from this comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36967#issuecomment-676698563

but it nuked all my containers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it through Docker, but ZFS is telling you that filesystem `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bl0u7i/var/lib/120f50d...bbdc40` had a couple clones created from snapshots on that filesystem. For the sake of argument let's say there's just one, and the cloned filesystem is called `clone1`, which was created off of `snapshot1` on the `rpool/...bbdc40` filesystem. So your hierarchy is like this:

```
rpool/...bbdc40 -> rpool/...bbdc40@snapshot1 -> clone1
```

The problem is that `clone1` is still referencing data from `snapshot1`, so you can't delete the snapshot, which prevents you from deleting the original filesystem.

However, ZFS allows you to change who the "parent" filesystem is by using the `zfs promote` command, which lets you change the hierarchy to this:

```
clone1 -> clone1@snapshot1 -> rpool/...bbdc40
```

Now nobody is depending on the data in `rpool/...bbdc40` (because the snapshot has been moved to be on the newly promoted parent, `clone1`), so you can delete it.

(That said, Docker probably assumes that it has full control over the state for its filesystems, so if you go around running random ZFS commands it risks making Docker sad and confused. Use at your own risk.)